# Datepicker UI - Change date with keycontrols

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hello I got a question regarding changing the date with the arrow keys on your keyboard (keycode 37,38,39,40).

If you look at this example: [DatePicker from Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/datepicker/overview/defaultcs.aspx) they have build a quite nice feature and I was wondering if that also could be achieved with the Datepicker jQuery UI widget.

Whenever you select a date within the Telerik Datepicker, for example: 9/14/2016, they have build that whenever you select a specific part of the date, let say the month value: `9`:
[image] and you press the up arrow key (keyCode 38) the month number is increased.

I have the functionality of navigating with those arrow keys through my Datebox. But I was wondering is this also possible inside the `input` field that is showing the current value as Telerik does?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, just not provided out-of-the-box (the datepicker widget is the div bound to the input, not the input itself). You can use the `which` and `selectionStart`/`selectionEnd` properties of a `keypress` event to figure out which date you want to set the value to.

Comment: Thanks! I will dig into that! @blgt